# Bind scope to Directive's Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Please consider the following angular directive:

```
 angular.module('map').directive('mapOptions',
    function MapOptionsDirective() {

      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
          map: '=',
          layers: '=',
          mapId: '@'
        },
        controller: mapOptionsController,
        controllerAs: 'mapOptionsCtrl',
        bindToController: true,
        templateUrl: 'modules/map/views/mapoptions.client.view.html'
      };


      ///////////////////////////

      function mapOptionsController($scope) {
        var vm = this;
        console.log(vm);              // log #1
        console.log($scope.map)       // log #2
        console.log(vm.map);          // log #3
      }
});
```

Note the isolated scope, the `controllerAs` syntax, as well as the `bindToController` option set to `true`.

This is how my directive looks in the html:

```
<map-options layers="mapCtrl.layers" map="mapCtrl.map" map-id="{{mapCtrl.mapId}}">
```

The log outputs are:

- log #1: Logs out `"constructor {}"`, which i guess is ok.
- log #2: Logs out the correct object that got bound to scope.
- log #3: Logs out `undefined`. This is, where i expected to find the object that i have found on `$scope`.

I want to bind the isolated scope to the controller directly, but this does not work. Strangely, the the scope gets filled with data, but this data is bound to scope, and does not get bound to the directive directly, as I would like it to. I cannot figure out, why. I must be missing something obvious. Thanks!

Comment: Hi , do you mind setting a CodePen or JSFiddle for that?

Comment: what version of angular are you using?

Comment: I am using angularjs v1.2.28.

Comment: I switched to a newer version of Angular (v1.3.16), and now it suddenly starts working! Thank you darkmyst for setting me on the right track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply had to switch from Angular1.2 to Angular1.3, and now it works as expected.

Comment: Yes, bindToController was added in 1.3